# Pandas fill empty trailing values with last known value

Tags: pandas

I have several columns with different ending time periods.

Need to fill the empty data with the last known value.

is there a Pandas way to do this without looping bases on the ending dates?

I need the gain_sum_y to equal -57129.0 for the last 4 months.

```
        gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
month                             
2014-09-30      -97747    -41355.0
2014-10-31     -112928    -47394.0
2014-11-30     -131638    -57129.0
2014-12-31     -161370         0.0
2015-01-31     -168832         0.0
2015-02-28     -151930         0.0
2015-03-31     -162077         0.0
```

thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`) if want replace all `0` values by last non `0` values:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan).ffill()
print (df)
        month  gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
0  2014-09-30      -97747    -41355.0
1  2014-10-31     -112928    -47394.0
2  2014-11-30     -131638    -57129.0
3  2014-12-31     -161370    -57129.0
4  2015-01-31     -168832    -57129.0
5  2015-02-28     -151930    -57129.0
6  2015-03-31     -162077    -57129.0
```

If you want specify column for replace (thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068609/pandas-fill-empty-trailing-values-with-last-known-value/46068619#comment79097801_46068619)):

```
df.replace({'gain_sum_y': {0: np.nan}}).ffill()
```

---

Sample with multiple `0`:

```
print (df)
            gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
month                             
2014-09-30      -97747    -41355.0
2014-10-31           0         0.0
2014-11-30           0    -57129.0
2014-12-31     -161370         0.0
2015-01-31     -168832         0.0
2015-02-28           0         0.0
2015-03-31     -162077         0.0

df1 = df.replace(0,np.nan).ffill()
print (df1)
            gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
month                             
2014-09-30    -97747.0    -41355.0
2014-10-31    -97747.0    -41355.0
2014-11-30    -97747.0    -57129.0
2014-12-31   -161370.0    -57129.0
2015-01-31   -168832.0    -57129.0
2015-02-28   -168832.0    -57129.0
2015-03-31   -162077.0    -57129.0
```

But if need replace only last `0` need [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) for replace last `0` to `NaN`:

```
df2 = df.replace(0,np.nan).apply(lambda x: x.loc[:x.last_valid_index()].fillna(0)).ffill()
print (df2)
            gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
2014-09-30    -97747.0    -41355.0
2014-10-31         0.0         0.0
2014-11-30         0.0    -57129.0
2014-12-31   -161370.0    -57129.0
2015-01-31   -168832.0    -57129.0
2015-02-28         0.0    -57129.0
2015-03-31   -162077.0    -57129.0
```

Comment: For specific column only do `df.replace({'gain_sum_y': {0: np.nan}}).ffill()`

Comment: my bad, I did not point out that there might be legitimate 0 value before the data starts.  Dealing with multiple time series.   So I need to only update the ENDING values after the last value posted.

Comment: OK, then use second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got to work:

```
# loop through all the columns
for i, column in enumerate ( df.columns ):

    # find the last row with value not zero
    x = df [ df[column] != 0 ].index [ -1 ]
    # get the last value before the zero values
    y = df[column] [x]
    # find and fill the rows greater than date "x" with value "y"
    mask = (df.index > x)
    df[column] [ mask ] = y
```

I hope this is good pandas. thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
df.fillna(method='pad')
```

have several columns with different ending time periods.

Need to fill the empty data with the last known value.

is there a Pandas way to do this without looping bases on the ending dates?

I need the gain_sum_y to equal -57129.0 for the last 4 months.

month |  gain_sum_x  | gain_sum_y
-|-|-
2014-09-30|      -97747|    -41355.0
2014-10-31|     -112928|    -47394.0
2014-11-30|     -131638|    -57129.0
2014-12-31|     -161370|         0.0
2015-01-31|     -168832|         0.0
2015-02-28|     -151930|         0.0
2015-03-31|     -162077|         0.0
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
mask = df['month'] > datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-12-01",'%Y-%m-%d')
df['gain_sum_y'][mask] = -57129.0 
df


month   gain_sum_x  gain_sum_y
0   2014-09-30  -97747  -41355.0
1   2014-10-31  -112928 -47394.0
2   2014-11-30  -131638 -57129.0
3   2014-12-31  -161370 -57129.0
4   2015-01-31  -168832 -57129.0
5   2015-02-28  -151930 -57129.0
6   2015-03-31  -162077 -57129.0
```